# How to remove a redirect of a URL from Angular Routing

Tags: angular

When visiting mywebsite.com I don't want it to redirect to mywebsite.com/home I would like it to stay at /

How do I do that as I am using Angular Routing?

I have looked at the Angular Docs and Googled it but couldn't seem to find the answer

Comment: Use this  `{
 path: '',
 redirectTo: '',
 pathMatch: 'full'
},{ path: 'home', redirectTo: '', component: HomeComponent },{ path: 'staff', component: StafflistComponent }, { path: 'players', component: PlayersComponent }, { path: 'profile', component: PlayersSearchComponent }, { path: 'parks', component: ParksComponent }, { path: 'community', component: CommunityComponent }, { path: 'creative', component: CreativeComponent }, { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }` use this set

Comment: what component do you want to load initialy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `HomeCompeont` to your root path in the route config

```js
[{
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
  .........
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app-routing.module.ts file and in the bottom of the file edit this snippet to:

```
{
 path: '',
 redirectTo: 'home',
 pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
 path: 'home',
 component: HomeComponent
}
```

Comment: Here is my routing paths. By adding that removes the homepage when I go to localhost:4200


```  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'staff', component: StafflistComponent },
  { path: 'players', component: PlayersComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: PlayersSearchComponent },
  { path: 'parks', component: ParksComponent },
  { path: 'community', component: CommunityComponent },
  { path: 'creative', component: CreativeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },```

Comment: Little bit more detail. When I go to mywebsite.com I don't want the /home displayed in the URL. It's fine having it for the other components but not home. When I tried to add the code snipet above it removed the /home but didn't load the home component only the Header and Footer